# Understanding Hibernate: JDBCExceptionReporter | Invalid parameter index

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting the following error when ever I try update particular information in a database, I have been looking online for a good bit now but I have been unable to find anywhere that explains what exactly the error is and what causes this error

```
2012-06-29 14:50:02,193 [project] ERROR [http-8080-2] JDBCExceptionReporter | Invalid parameter index 57.
2012-06-29 14:50:02,209 [project] ERROR [http-8080-2] AbstractFlushingEventListener | Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not update: [com.company.project.PSDBusinessAssociate#18962]
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at      org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2360)
at  org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2242)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2542)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:92)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:248)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:232)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:140)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:655)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:709)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:678)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:321)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:116)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:635)
at com.fexco.wuams.service.dwr.BusinessAssociateFormService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$cb75a250.updateBusinessAssociate(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter$1.doFilter(DefaultRemoter.java:740)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:744)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:593)
at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallHandler.handle(BaseCallHandler.java:90)
at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:120)
at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:141)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:265)
at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:124)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:228)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:212)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:818)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:445)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid parameter index 57.
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.getParameter(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:255)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.setParameter(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:326)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.setLong(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:509)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setLong(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:703)
at org.hibernate.type.LongType.set(LongType.java:42)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:83)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:60)
at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:78)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1932)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2306)
... 57 more
```

this appears in my error output on screen

```
could not update: [com.company.project.dataobject.PSDBusinessAssociate#18962]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not update: [com.company.project.dataobject.PSDBusinessAssociate#18962]
```

so my question is what exactly does this error mean and what causes this error to occur?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the SQL that hibernate is generating isn't valid.  This can often mean that your mappings are incorrect (such as incorrect column/table names).  A good way to debug SQL Grammer exceptions is to set hibernate.show_sql=true and hibernate.format_sql=true in your SessionFactory.  Hibernate will output generated sql to the console for you to verify.

Comment: I will give this ago, i will use `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=ALL, SQL_APPENDER` to log the code to the console as I am using log4j... I will get back when I have played around with this

Comment: just looking at it there and all the columns and table names are all correct, could this error be triggers by hibernate trying to insert the wrong variable into a field in a table (e.g. double instead of an int) ?

Comment: Could be.  Try setting up a logger for org.hibernate.type=TRACE, I think that will show you the values that hibernate is putting into the prepared statement

Comment: i managed to set it up and looking through the values that it is inserting into the database, it looks like it is getting all the values correctly but it is adding a few of them in the wrong order... while check it out now fully +1 for all the help as well even if this isnt the answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rebuilding your database through a Hibernate command? (I know Netbeans allows you to do this, dunno if it runs an `ant` script behind the scenes...) and seeing if it works?

Maybe someone edited the database manually without you knowing (or you yourself!) and Hibernate finds a table structure different than it is expecting when accessing the database...